# fetch api and json

Tags: json, fetch-api, console.log

For some reason the second then command in my js file line 12 seems to be nonconductant. 
Why is that ?  Thanks

Edit: The questionn should have been : For some reason the second console.log does not give an output.

This question has been sucessfully answered by the commentators. Thank you

[codepen](https://codepen.io/wolverinevie/pen/REQEOb)

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', btnPressed);

function btnPressed() {

  fetch("https://randomuser.me/api")
    .then(function(res) {
      console.log(res);
      return res.json();

    })
    .then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
    })
    .catch(err => console.log('Error,with     message:', err.statusText))
}
```

```html
<button id=btn>Button</button>
```

Comment: What does “nonconductant” mean?

Comment: it means it doesn  not function, as in it doesnot give print a console log(data)

Comment: It works when I test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Both console.log functions are working... Please run the below code.





    document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', btnPressed);

    function btnPressed() {

      fetch("https://randomuser.me/api")
        .then(function(res) {
console.log("...................1st console Start");
          console.log(res);
console.log("...................1st console End");
          return res.json();

        })
        .then(function(data) {
console.log("...................2nd console Start");
          console.log(data);
console.log("...................2nd console End");
        })
        .catch(err => console.log('Error,with     message:', err.statusText))
    }
    <button id=btn>Button</button>
```

Comment: okay thanks. i discovered the first console.log shows the response and the second the json object. Thanks for the help

Comment: Ok, thanks again for the help. I see now the console.log(res) returns the api response   while console.log(data) returns the object